# Problem in Beamer: how to customize citations

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing

I'm trying to customize citations in beamer.

Let me include a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}



\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false]{biblatex}
%\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\longcite}{}{\textcolor{magenta}{[\scriptsize   %
        \printnames[author]{author}, \printfield{journaltitle}, \printfield{year}]}}{;}{}%  



%------------------------------ slides aspect ----------------------------------------
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\begin{document}
    


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item \emph{Isogeometric analysis}~\cite{MR2152382}
\item \emph{Isogeometric analysis}~\longcite{MR2152382}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{References}
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Here is the output I get.

[image]

[image]

I would like to customize the command \longcite in such a way that I could refer just to the family names of the authors and an abbreviated name of the journal (provided there is such a field in the respective bibliography item), e.g., CMAME in this case. Any help?

Let us assume that the bibliography item reads as follows.

```
@article{MR2152382,
    author = {Hughes, Thomas J. R. and Cottrell, J. Austin and Bazilevs, Yuri},
    date-added = {2021-07-30 11:49:08 +0200},
    date-modified = {2022-01-14 13:02:42 +0100},
    doi = {10.1016/j.cma.2004.10.008},
    fjournal = {Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering},
    issn = {0045-7825},
    journal = {Comput. Methods Appl. Mech. Engrg.},
    journal_abbr = {CMAME},
    mrclass = {65D17 (65N30 74S05)},
    mrnumber = {2152382},
    number = {39-41},
    pages = {4135--4195},
    title = {Isogeometric analysis: {CAD}, finite elements, {NURBS}, exact geometry and mesh refinement},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cma.2004.10.008},
    volume = {194},
    year = {2005},
    bdsk-url-1 = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cma.2004.10.008}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beamer` is largely irrelevant for your request, so in the code example below I will switch to the standard `article` class. Of course the answer still works with `beamer`.

In the `biblatex` standard model the field for the abbreviated journal name is `shortjournal` and not `journal_abbr`. If you switch from `journal_abbr` to `shortjournal`, you can use the following idea.

The definition of `\longcite` is modelled more closely on the definition of cite commands of the standard styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  style=alphabetic,
  doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro{longcite}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {\printfield{journaltitle}}
    {\printfield[journaltitle]{shortjournal}}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate
}

\newcommand*{\mkbibsmallcolouredbrackets}[1]{%
  \textcolor{magenta}{%
    \mkbibbrackets{%
      {\scriptsize #1}%
    }%
  }%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\longcite}[\mkbibsmallcolouredbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{longcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{MR2152382,
  author       = {Hughes, Thomas J. R. and Cottrell, J. Austin and Bazilevs, Yuri},
  doi          = {10.1016/j.cma.2004.10.008},
  fjournal     = {Computer Methods in Applied Mechanics and Engineering},
  journal      = {Comput. Methods Appl. Mech. Engrg.},
  shortjournal = {CMAME},
  number       = {39-41},
  pages        = {4135--4195},
  title        = {Isogeometric Analysis:
                  {CAD}, Finite Elements, {NURBS}, Exact Geometry
                  and Mesh Refinement},
  volume       = {194},
  year         = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,MR2152382}

ipsum \longcite{sigfridsson,MR2152382}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [SR98; HCB05] ipsum [Sigfridsson and Ryde, Journal of Computational Chemistry, 1998; Hughes, Cottrell, and Bazilevs, CMAME, 2005]]

Comment: Thank you a lot for the very clear answer! Best regards, Riccardo

Comment: and if I want to refer to the year as the last two digits, e.g. instead of 2017 just 17. How should I proceed?